# Throwing exceptions in a database wrapper

Tags: c#, database, error-handling, wrapper

I hope the extension methods `ThrowArgumentNullExceptionIfNullOrEmpty` and `ThrowNullReferenceExceptionIfNullOrEmpty` are straightforward.

I have a property in my class called `ConnectionString`. I can set this property through a method called `SetConnectionString`.

```
public static void SetConnectionString(string connectionString)
{
        _connectionString = connectionString.ThrowArgumentNullExceptionIfNullOrEmpty("connectionString", Localizer.GetString("0x000000004"));
}
```

My reason why I don't have

```
public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }
```

but

```
public static string ConnectionString { get { return _connectionString; } }
```

is because I want the property to be read-only and throw an `ArgumentNullException` if the argument in `SetConnectionString` is null or empty.

Since the `class` is `static`, it's possible for `ConnectionString` to be `null` (or an empty string if I do this: `return _connectionString ?? ""`).

**Part 1**

In the code below I check the arguments for null or an empty string but to prevent an exception occurring when calling `OpenConnection` (see *Part 2* for more on this method) I also check if the `_connectionString` (`private` variable of the `ConnectionString` property) is not null or empty (empty is for the internal connection string of the `OleDbConnection` object). Here I decided the exception should be a `NullReferenceException` because it's not directly an argument of the method.

Is this the correct approach to handle this situation? Consider that the code in between the checks might and might not have an impact on the application if the `using` fails.

```
public static int GetHighestID(string table, string column)
{
    _connectionString.ThrowNullReferenceExceptionIfNullOrEmpty(Localizer.GetString("0x000000000"));

    table.ThrowArgumentNullExceptionIfNullOrEmpty("table", Localizer.GetString("0x000000001"));

    column.ThrowArgumentNullExceptionIfNullOrEmpty("column", Localizer.GetString("0x000000002"));

    // Some other things are happening here ...

    using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(_connectionString))
    using (var command = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("SELECT MAX({0}) FROM {1}", column, table), connection))
    {
        OpenConnection(connection);

        return (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

**Part 2**

The `OpenConnection` method as mentioned before is included below.

```
public static void OpenConnection(OleDbConnection connection)
{
    connection.ThrowArgumentNullExceptionIfNull("connection", Localizer.GetString("0x00000000C"));
    connection.ConnectionString.ThrowArgumentNullExceptionIfNullOrEmpty("connection.ConnectionString", Localizer.GetString("0x00000000F"));

    if (connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        connection.Open();
}
```

I also here check if the `OleDbConnection` object is not null and that the internal connection string is not null or an empty string. My intention is to always use this method when opening the connection with the database.

Again, is this the correct approach to handle this situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you want your database wrapper to be `static`? What if you want to mock it in your unit tests?

I would make it a plain old `class`, pass the connection string through the constructor and do any kind of checks that I want *right there*, because that means your database wrapper won't be allowed to even exist without a valid connection string. With your current design, you're forced to check the connection string in each method, therefore duplicating code, and duplication is generally a no-no.

Static classes do have their use cases, but this is really not one of them. You usually want to write static classes to group methods that don't deal with any specific object, but here you *are* indeed dealing with something that, being a database, is about as specific as it gets.

Also, what's the `GetHighestID` method for?
I'm asking because I had to deal with codebases that, instead of letting the database do the auto-increment, would exactly do a `SELECT MAX(Id)` and add 1 before doing `INSERT`s.

In case that *is* what you're doing, then stop, because it defeats the purpose of having an auto-increment column at all. Also, the fact that the column is set to auto-increment is something your code shouldn't need to know about. As far as your code is concerned, all it needs to know is the name of the field that is the designated key for the table.
Plus, a database can handle auto-increments much better than you ever will, even more so when it comes to concurrent writes.

Last but not least, exceptions. Don't throw `NullReferenceException`s. That's the job of CLR, not yours. Now, with my design the need to throw it just goes away, but I just thought I would mention this. Throwing a `NullReferenceException` manually stinks.

### Edit

> Well, the reason why I made it static is because the class has to be
>   used in several classes. I have for ex. classes like Item, Person,
>   Factory, ... which all have an interaction to the database. Each class
>   has an Insert, Update, ... method. In my POV it looks easier to set
>   the connection once e.g. while starting the application and then be
>   able to use the class everywhere without having to initialize it every
>   time.

You're right that it *looks* easier, but it really is not.

Let's examine the options we have here:

1. a static database wrapper, this would be your design
2. a non-static class
3. a non-static class implementing an interface

Option 2 would look like this:

```
class ClientClass
{
    private readonly Database _database;

    public ClientClass()
    {
        _database = new Database(ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Now, the problem with options 1 and 2 is that, should you ever want to write unit tests for one of the classes that uses your database wrapper *without* actually issuing queries to the database, you would be out of luck.

And since you *should* be writing unit tests, you *are* indeed out of luck.

Why is that, though? Because you can't create a class that *looks* like your database wrapper *but*, for instance, returns the data you decide upon calling a hypothetical `Select` method.

Option 1 doesn't allow that because, even if you wrote such a class, you would have no way of substituting your `FakeDatabase` class without physically replacing `FakeDatabase` with `Database` in all the classes that use it. Static classes are initialized only once, so how are you going to swap the real implementation with a fake one?

Option 2 doesn't allow that either, because the name of your database wrapper is wired in the constructor of the class. There is still no way you can swap `Database` with `FakeDatabase`without touching the code.

Plus, option 2 is just bad because now your client classes need to *know* that a connection string exists at all, when they really shouldn't.

Option 3 is described down here:

> From what you say I understand that I should initialize the
>   class each time and pass the connection string before calling the
>   method. If not, what approach would you suggest?

That's correct. As @craftworkgames said, classes that need to communicate with the database get an instance of the database wrapper passed in, generally through the constructor.

To be even more precise, once your database wrapper is ready, you will want to extract an interface, let's call it `IDatabase`, that exposes all the wrapper's public method, and have your wrapper implement it.

Client classes, then, will have a constructor such as this:

```
class ClientClass
{
    private readonly IDatabase _database;

    public ClientClass(IDatabase database)
    {
         _database = database;
    }
}
```

Now you're golden, because if `FakeDatabase` implements `IDatabase` too, when writing a unit test you can pass in an instance of `FakeDatabase` with your client class none the wiser.

Client classes only need to know that the class you pass in exposes a certain set of methods. It does and should not know anything about how and from where that class pulls the data it returns, or where it writes to. Is it a RDBMS? Is it an XML file? Something else altogether? Client classes don't have to care about that, which is good, because it gives you the option to swap data stores without changing anything else.

Option 3 is called **dependency injection**. All the information you need is just a google away.

You could also read about:

1. programming to the interface, not the implementation
2. unit testing
3. mock objects

Lastly, this concept of making classes as unaware of the workings of other classes as possible, applies to every level of your architecture. A database layer just happens to be one of the prime examples.

Gosh, I hope all of that made sense.

Comment: Well, the reason why I made it `static` is because the class has to be used in several classes. I have for ex. classes like Item, Person, Factory, ... which all have an interaction to the database. Each class has an Insert, Update, ... method. In my POV it looks easier to set the connection once e.g. while starting the application and then be able to use the class everywhere without having to initialize it every time. From what you say I understand that I should initialize the class each time and pass the connection string before calling the method. If not, what approach would you suggest?

Comment: Classes that need to interact with the database typically get a reference to the database class in their own constructors.

Comment: @Krowi I edited the answer.

Comment: Very nicely written.  It helped solidify some concepts for me.